# Unable to activate money-6.12.0, because i18n-1.1.0 conflicts with i18n (< 1.1, >= 0.6.4) (Gem::ConflictError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm create a Spree 3.6 application, app create successfully then i started to create an extension and that extension depend on doorkeeper , the issue i that when i try rails g doorkeeper:install i get the below error.

```
Unable to activate money-6.12.0, because i18n-1.1.0 conflicts with i18n (< 1.1, >= 0.6.4) (Gem::ConflictError)
```

my configuration is rails 5.2 & ruby 2.5.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my issue with the following

```
gem uninstall i18n --all --force
gem install i18n --version 0.9.5
```